# Code to save file as PDF but corrupts the file and unable to view

Tags: excel, vba

The code works but the file gets corrupted and I am unable to view the file. I can't tell where the mistake is.

I have this code written to save the workbook as a PDF and when activated, needs to bring up the SaveAs box - there is an issues sometimes with the file path not work as well.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    
    Dim FileName As Variant
    
    'Displaying the saveas dialog box
    FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Invoice #.pdf", "PDF,*.pdf", 1, " 'where my current file path will be to store my PDF files ")

    'User didn't save a file
    If TypeName(FileName) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    
    'Save the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that changing the fixe extension to PDF does not turn a XLSX file into a PDF file. The file format needs to be correct too.

This `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName` does not save a file as PDF but as Excel Workbook, because no filetype was specified!

Check the official documentation of the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas), and choose the correct `FileFormat` according [xlFileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).

In case of PDF you need to export instead of save. Therefore see the [Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) and choose a `Type` according [xlFixedFormatType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfixedformattype):

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileName
```